# Test styles triggered by mouse over events

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a button that displays different styles when mouse moves over it:

```
background-color: green;
&:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Here is my test:

```
fireEvent.mouseOver(button);

expect(button).toHaveStyle(`
  background-color: red;
`);
```

However, the test complained that the background color is green instead of red.
I tried `fireEvent.mouseEnter` before calling `mouseOver`. Didn't make any difference. What did I miss?

Comment: No solution, but question also asked here: https://spectrum.chat/thread/108403f4-915b-4243-974c-c41af826b91d

Comment: mouseOver in react-testing-library is asynchronous, you need to wait for it.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786789/mouseenter-mouseover-doesnt-work-with-react-testing-library-how-to-test-hover

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the event to be fired and the style to be applied. You can try

```
fireEvent.mouseOver(button);

expect(await button).toHaveStyle(`
  background-color: red;
`);
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can wrap it in act().