# react testing library - test window.addEventListener('mouseout')

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, react-testing-library, testing-library

I have a modal component which will trigger when the users mouse leaves the window.
I have archived this via a useEffect hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => { if (e.toElement == null && e.relatedTarget == null) {
      e.preventDefault();
      handleTrigger();
    }
  });
return function cleanup() {
  document.removeEventListener('mouseout', (e) => { if (e.toElement == null && e.relatedTarget == null) {
      e.preventDefault();
      handleTrigger();
    }
   });
  };
});
```

I am not sure how to obtain full code coverage for this using react testing library.
I have tried a few methods but the most recent is displayed below.

```
  it('should remove window eventListener', () => {

    const modal = render(<Modal />);

    const eListenerBefore = (event) => {

      expect(event.defaultPrevented).toBe(true);

      window.removeEventListener('mouseout', eListenerBefore);

    };

    window.addEventListener('mouseout', eListenerBefore);

    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseout'));

 

    const radioBtn = modal.queryByLabelText('Other');

    fireEvent.click(radioBtn);

    const submitBtn = modal.queryByTestId('abandonment-survey-modal-button-submit');

    fireEvent.click(submitBtn);

 

    const eListenerAfter = (event) => {

      expect(event.defaultPrevented).toBe(false);

      window.removeEventListener('mouseout', eListenerAfter);

    };

 

    window.addEventListener('mouseout', eListenerAfter);

    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseout'));

  });
```

when I trigger the modal using `window.dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseout'));` the modal displays and I can dismiss it but my test does not pass and there is no code coverage.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you need to use async/await to wait for the screen to change, like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786789/mouseenter-mouseover-doesnt-work-with-react-testing-library-how-to-test-hover) suggests.